# Do the cursed servants in Beast's castle grow older?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast

We know the Beast ages; I think he was eleven or something when he was cursed and he's 21 years old when the rose's last petal falls.

But what about the servants? For example: was Chip a baby that became a baby-tea-cup who has grown into a 10-yr-old tea cup? Or has he stayed the age he was when the curse fell on him.

---

<sup><sub>Bonus points: Who even is Chip and his fellow tiny tea cups in the cupboard? Like, why were there a bunch of babies/10-yr-olds in the castle?</sub></sup>

Comment: They were the children of the servants, naturally (in answer to the subscript question).

Comment: Concering the _duration_ of the spell, it could be noted that it is cited only once in the song _Be our guest_ (_"10 years we've been rusting"_), which could be considered a poetic licence, an approximation or a slight exaggeration on Lumiere's part. Moreover, in the _live action_ movie the line is changed to _"too long we've been rusting"_, maybe in an attempt to handwave similar timeline issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other teacups are explictly confirmed to be Mrs Potts' children (Chip's brothers and sisters) in the Disney Comics "[Official Comic Adaptation](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Beauty_and_the_Beast_Official_Comic_Adaptation)" of the film.

[image]

In the tie-in film [Beauty and the Best: The Enchanted Christmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty_and_the_Beast:_The_Enchanted_Christmas) we see Chip (and the other servants) prior to their being cursed. The prince is clearly younger whereas the servants are much the same age. Chip, in particular doesn't appear to have aged ***by ten years*** in the intervening decade.

[image]

Comment: Concerning the cups: the exact lines in the comic panel are present in the movie too (at 00:35:22); a few times, for example at about 00:20:36, Chip calls Mrs Potts "Mama".

Comment: I haven't seen _"The Enchanted Christmas"_, but in the screenshot Chip seems to be really small and wearing a bib (so 1 y.o.? 2?) while at the end of the movie he seems definitely grown up (even if not _10 years_ older ... maybe it's the antioxidant in the tea?).